# Need help sorting a SingleLinkedList alphabetically

Tags: java, comparator, compareto

My program is meant to read a text file and insert the names into a singlelinkedlist and print the names alphabetically.There is a compareTo and equals method in the name class that needs to be utilized in the singlelinkedlist class. In the singleLinkedList class I used the addToList method to initially create the list. I manage to get every name into the list but I have no idea how to go about using the compareTo method to sort the list alphabetically in the singlelinkedlist class. Here is my code:
Name class:

```
     public class Name implements Comparator<Name> {
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;
    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
       super();
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String toString(){
       return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
   public int compareTo(Name name){
      return (this.firstName).compareTo(name.firstName);
   }
    /**
    * @return the firstName
    */
    public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
    }
    /**
    * @param firstName the firstName to set
    */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /**
    * @return the lastName
    */
    public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
    }
    /**
    * @param lastName the lastName to set
    */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    }
```

SingleLinkedList class:

```
public class SingleLinkedList {
   private static Node head;
   private int listCount;
/**
* No-arg constructor
*/
public SingleLinkedList()
{
}
/**
* adds node to start
* @param name
*/
public void addToStart(Name name)
{
   head = new Node(name, head);
   listCount++;
}
/**
* adds node to list
* @param name
*/
public void addToList(Name name)
{
if(head != null)
{
   Node curr = head;
while(curr.next != null)
{
   curr = curr.next;
}
   curr.next = new Node(name);
}
else
{
   head = new Node(name);
}
   listCount++;
}
/**
* Number of nodes in the list
* 
* @return list count
*/
public int size()
{
   return listCount;
}
public String toString()
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   Node curr = head;
if(curr != null)
{
while(curr.next != null)
{
   sb.append(curr.name.toString());
   sb.append("\n");
   curr = curr.next;
}
   sb.append(curr.name.toString());
}
   return sb.toString();
}
private class Node
{
   private Name name;
   private Node next;
public Node(Name name)
{
   this.name=name;
   next = null;
}
public Node(Name name, Node next)
{
   this(name);
   this.next = next;
}
}
}
```

Main Driver:

```
public class ClassListDriver {

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
String filename="179ClassList.txt";
Scanner inputStream=null;
SingleLinkedList sll= new SingleLinkedList();
try
{
   inputStream=new Scanner(new File(filename));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
   System.out.println("Error opening the file.");
   System.exit(0);
}
while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){
   String[] data=inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
   String firstName=data[0];
   String lastName=data[1];
   Name name= new Name(firstName,lastName);
   sll.addToList(name);
}
System.out.println(sll);
System.out.println(sll.size());
}

}
```

Comment: Here is resolved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410241/sorting-a-list-alphabetically-using-compareto-method?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a comparator on your Name class.

```
public class Name implements Comparator<Name>{

// Overriding the compareTo method
   public int compareTo(Name name){
      return (this.firstName).compareTo(name.firstName);
   }
}
```

Comment: How do I utilize this method to sort my list though?